# Cant install NPM as user not root

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

So I've tried to fix this my self for a couple hours and I feel I've made it worse.  I am running Kbuntu 12.10, and trying to install nodejs and npm as a user not root so I can install the game closure framework.  I had a version of node and npm installed as root.  Then tried to install it again (without removing the old) via these instructions: http://tnovelli.net/blog/blog.2011-08-27.node-npm-user-install.html

Now when I type `which npm` I get nothing.  However when I type `which node` i get `/home/myusername/.local/bin/node`. So I am assuming node is installed correctly.

also when I type `npm -v`

I get:

```
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm
```

So I type `sudo apt-get install npm`

and the response is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
npm : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: nodejs-dev
   Depends: node-node-uuid but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this so I can install npm according to the link above?

EDIT: after searching some more i tried `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`
and even after that I still get the same message after attempting to apt-get npm

Comment: npm is packaged with node, you shouldn't be installing it seperately. You also shouldn't be using distributor packages because they are grossly out of date. Try [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: I will try nvm, and the post I referred to actually uses the the main node package from nodejs.org. The thing I need most is to not have node run in root.

Comment: I install node using `nvm` and start scripts like `sudo node myscript.js` all the time.